# Error while doing POST 'UserCreationForm' object has no attribute 'is_vaild'

Tags: python, django, forms, attributes, django-2.1

I'm a django learner and I was trying to create user registration form using the in-build `UserCreationForm`.

### **view.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_vaild():
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            return redirect('blog-home')
    else:
        form = UserCreationForm()

    return render(request, 'users/register.html',{'form':form})
```

While trying to `POST` i'm receiving `'UserCreationForm' object has no attribute 'is_vaild'`. If i understand correctly for all the django forms there will be a is_valid function to validate.

Please help  me to find what am i missing here.

Let me know if you need any other file details.

I'm using Django 2.1,Python 3.6

Comment: You misspelled it, it should be `is_valid` not `is_vaild`

Comment: I'm so embarrassed right now. Sometime you forget to keep an eye on minute details.

Answer (score 0):

As Abdul Niyas said, change `is_vaild` to `is_valid`.

Answer (score 0):

Please take in mind that you still need to send something in case the form is invalid !form.is_valid() added a few lines to your code, BTW your simply mispelled **is_valid()**

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            return redirect('blog-home')
        else:
            # Show user form errors with {% form.errors %} on the template.
            return render(request, 'users/register.html', {'form': form})
    else:
        form = UserCreationForm()

    return render(request, 'users/register.html',{'form':form})
```